# Backbone persistant view with persistant data

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views

I have a navigation bar that is pretty much the only piece of persistant template in my web application (in that is always there regardless of route).

In that navbar I show a Login link if the user is not logged in, and if they are I show their name, the problem I having is that I can't get the nav to keep it's state. The uses logins,

```
runLogin: function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var element = $(e.currentTarget),
        self = this;

    $.when($.ajax({
        url: 'http://app-api.dev/api/oauth/access_token?grant_type=password&client_id=1&client_secret=xyz',
        method: 'POST',
        data: element.serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {

            // Set the cookie, this will need to be sent in every singal request going foward.
            $.cookie('access_token', data.access_token);
            // So we have the access token we use this to populate our user details

        },
        error: function(response) {
            // We can build a universal error view that would be quite and pretty easy to do.
        }
    })).done(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://app-api.dev/api/users/me',
            dataType: 'json',
            method: 'GET',
            success:function(user) {
                self.model.set(user);
                self.launchDashboard();
            }
        });
    })
},

launchDashboard: function() {
    localStorage.setItem('user', '');
    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(this.me));
    App.Routes.Application.navigate('dashboard', { trigger: true } );
}
```

Basically I login, request my details from the API, and use those to set a model, the model I am setting has already been passed in to the navigation view, and has a change listener on it.

```
showUserDetails: function() {
    this.loggedInUserMenu = new App.Views.navigationViewLoggedIn({
        model : this.model
    });
},
```

the above fires this,

```
App.Views.navigationViewLoggedIn = Backbone.View.extend({

el: '.navbar-right',

template: _.template( $('#tpl-navigation-logged-in').html() ),

events: {

},

initialize: function() {
    this.render();
},

render: function() {
    this.$('.li-login').replaceWith( this.template({
        user: this.model.toJSON()
    }));
}
```

});

**Router**

```
initialize: function() {

    Pops.Models.AuthUser = new Pops.Models.User;

    this.navigation_bar = new Pops.Views.navigationView({
        model: Pops.Models.AuthUser
    });

},
```

On successful login the loggedInNavigation is visisble, and I am at `app-client.dev/#dashboard` however if I navigate to `app-client.dev/#groups I lose the loggedInNavigation and it reverts back to just saying "login".

Why?

=== Edit I ahve attached the method that creates the main nav it is done on the initialize of the routes. The method that does the view update is all the in the previous code, login sets the model that is int he navigation view, listening for a change ===

Comment: could you please attach your router and piece of code where u update page content ?

Comment: who owns and launch `runLogin` method ?

Comment: The user triggers runLogin. It is in the loginView triggered by a form submit.